# Proof that the subset relation is reflexive and transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, self-learning

I'm teaching myself set theory, and I'm not sure how detailed I should be when asked to prove things.

Here is my proof that $A\subseteq A$ (the subset relation is reflexive):

$A \subseteq B$ iff $((x \in A) \implies (x \in B))$

$A \subseteq A$ iff $((x \in A) \implies (x \in A))$

$(x \in A) \implies (x \in A)$ is always true, as something implying itself must be true (is there a formal way to write this?)

Hence $ A \subseteq A$ is always true.

Is this proof formal enough, and does it contain the right amount of detail?

Comment: this proof Is formal enough and it contains the right amount of detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Your proof is right.*

Two comments :

*(i)* Instead of $A⊆B \implies ((x∈A) \implies (x∈B))$ I prefer :

> $A⊆B$ **iff** $((x∈A) \implies (x∈B))$

because the RHS is the *definition* of set inclusion.

*(ii)* $x \in A \implies x \in A$ is an instance of the "logical law" :

> $\mathcal A \implies \mathcal A$

which is a *tautology* of *propositional logic*.

The rules of logic allow us to substitute for the *propositional letter* $\mathcal A$ a formula whatever, and the result is still true, provided that we replace all the occurrences of $\mathcal A$ with the same formula.

Comment: So how would I write (ii) in the proof? Would I just write "which must be true by the logical law"?

Comment: @sweeneyrod - exactly as you did. $(x∈A) \implies (x∈A)$ is always true, because it is an instance of the "logical law" (*tautology*) : $A \implies A$. My second comment was only intended to "supplement" your proof, specifically answering to "(is there a formal way to write this?)".

Comment: @sweeneyrod - additional comment (maybe superfluous) : $\subseteq$ is also *antisymmetric*. Thus, it is a [Partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)

Answer (score 2):

User wrote:

> $(x \in A) \implies (x \in A)$ is always true, as something implying itself must be true (is there a formal way to write this?)

This is certainly more than rigorous enough for most math courses, even at the highest level.

However, to make it a truly formal proof, depending on the axioms and rules you are allowed, you would need something along the lines of:

1. $x\in A$ (Premise)
2. $x\in A\implies x\in A$ (Conclusion)
3. $\forall a:[a\in A\implies a\in A]$ (Universal Generalization)

On each numbered line, you would have to cite the specific axiom or rule used to obtain that result. In my example, I refer to axioms of logic called Premise, Conclusion and Universal Generalization (names and usage will vary). Generally, in a *formal* proof, it's one line, one rule. Fortunately, most courses will not require this level of detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm practicing my set proving skills. Maybe somebody could benefit from it, or point out an error in the solution.

The proof for

${A \subseteq A}$

${\forall_x, [(x \in A) \to (x \in A)]}$ def subset

${\forall_x, [\lnot(x \in A) \lor (x \in A)]}$ implication conversion law

${\forall_x, T}$ law of excluded middle

So the statement is reduced to a tautology, so therefor it must be true.